# Using C# dll in Windows phone 7

Tags: dllimport

I've tried using C# dll in Windows phone 7 but it occurs error after start debugging as illustrated below.

---

Troubleshooding tips:
 If the access level of a method in a class library has changed, recompile any assemblies that reference that library.
 Get generral help for this exception.

---

This is the code..

-----------------Windows Phone 7-----------------------------------------------

```
using System;
...
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DllLoadTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("MathLibrary.dll")]
        public static extern int AddInteger(int a, int b);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test " + AddInteger(3, 4));
        }
    }
}
```

---

------------------------C#  MathLibrary.dll----------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MathLibrary
{
    public class Add
    {
        public static long AddInteger(long i, long j)
        {
            return i + j;
        }
    }
}
```

---

is there any problem? if not, using C# dll for WindowsPhone7 is impossible?
The C# Dll loaded well in visualstudio2008 C#.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to use P/Invoke on a class library written in C#? Just add a reference to the DLL and use it directly:

```
using MathLibrary;
...

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test " + Add.AddInteger(3, 4));
}
```

You can't use P/Invoke in Windows Phone 7, but you *can* use class libraries (built for Windows Phone 7).

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I have one more question. you said that I can use class libraries(built for Windows Phone 7). does it mean that the libraries have to be built by 'Windows Phone Class Library' in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: @Angdro: It's not entirely clear to me, but I *believe* so. Certainly that's what I've always done with the class libraries I'm using.

Comment: Thank Jon it helps me a lot. have a great day.